# Reading php file from a website using Java?

Tags: java, php, execute

I am aware that you can use Java to execute the php file from a website like below:

```
URLConnection conn = new URL("http://localhost/file.php").openConnection();
conn.connect();
```

However would it be possible to make Java read the php file as a text file and how? (Possibly via the use of the BufferedReader)

Thank you.

Comment: Edit: Would it be possible to use Java to read php source code? Similarly to HTML where you could use the BufferedReader to parse its source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to read the `php` source, then the answer is no - you cannot read `php` source in a typical webserver configuration. In most cases it would be very insecure to allow it - passwords and other constants are often stored in `php` source code.

If however, you are just meaning to read out the result of executing the `php` document, as a browser would do, you can use something like;

```
URL u = new URL("http://www.example.com/my/php/doc.php");
URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
InputStream r = c.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(r));
for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) System.out.println(line);
```

---

To read the source of a remote `php` document via http, the webserver needs to be configured to *not* parse & execute the file, rather just serve it blindly as a plain text file.

This can be achieved in a few ways;

1. Uninstall `php` - no php engine, no code execution.
2. Change the file extension - apache actually just identifies files by their file extension, so changing it to `.phpsource` would do the trick in many instances.
3. Alter the apache configuration - either globally, or via `.htaccess` you can alter webserver configurations for a single directory. You would want to do something like `php_flag engine off` or `RemoveHandler .php`

Note that only the first, and *maybe* the second, method above **does not** open up potential security holes in your server. So use with caution.

Comment: Edit: Would it be possible to use Java to read php source code? Similarly to HTML where you could use the BufferedReader to parse its source.

Comment: Yeah it is possible, but you would have to reconfigure the webserver. I will edit my answer.